# google places API no returning results

Tags: android, google-api, gps, location, google-places-api

google places API returning on calling it from android using urlConnection, and also from the package provided in credentials. 
still showing/returning the below as json data:

```
{
"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to        use this API key. Request received from IP address 120.59.69.127, with empty referer",
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

on trying the link

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.6142552,77.09509802&radius=5000&types=atm&sensor=false&key=[MY_API_KEY_for_android]

on trying a browser key or server key the json data fetched is

```
{ "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Like the `error_message` says, your API key isn't configured to allow this use.  To use that URL please check that you 1) have the "Google Places API Web Service" API enabled in the Google Developers Console, and 2) that you are using **Server** key, and 3) that it has no IP address restrictions [or if you want IP address restrictions that they match the IP you are querying from].

Comment: thanks that worked. i hadn't enabled Web service api

Comment: Great!  I'll paste that comment into an answer then, for posterity :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the `error_message` says, your API key isn't configured to allow this use. To use that URL please check that you

1. have the "Google Places API Web Service" API enabled in the Google Developers Console, and
2. that you are using **Server** key, and
3. that it has no IP address restrictions [or if you want IP address restrictions that they match the IP you are querying from].